# Selenium: Click timeout on opening of modal dialog

Tags: c#, selenium, modal-dialog, browser-automation

Currently I am automating an editor within a CMS, which includes a wide choices of options such as inserting links and changing the text color.

The issue I am facing is that upon clicking one of the toolbar buttons, a javascript command is executed launching a modal dialog

for some reason this modal dialog box causes my code to hang on the click command until it either has been manually closed or the click times out after 60 seconds

Here is a sample of my code

```
try
{
     // the click that opens the modal dialog
     driver.FindElement(By.Id("CreatArticle")).Click();

     // the code then hangs on the click command above until
     //it times out or the modal dialog is manually closed
     System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("This message box never shows");
}
catch(exception e)
{
     //this writes the exception to an error log
     testLog("Page creation failed, reason: " + e);
}
```

The exception message I recieve

```
> Article creation failed, reason: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException:
> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
> http://localhost:63377/session/adde8cea404a930e9086e1782afcbcf5/element/0.03468421520665288-16/click
> timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
> operation has timed out    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() 
> at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest
> request) in
> c:\Projects\webdriver\dotnet\src\webdriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:line
> 142    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I have also tried to click the toolbar button via a js.executeScript() command and was greeted with the same results, however the exception was "execute timed out after 60 seconds".

One option I have been suggested is multithreading, with the second thread handling the dialog box whilst the initial thread is hanging. Is selenium capable of this or is there another approach I can try?

EDIT
Here is an example i have found of my issue
https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/showModalDialog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my own problem

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=284

## 134 de...@mingulov.com

Hi all,

A workaround working for me on Firefox for the same issue - to use an async click, by for example JavaScript setTimeout.

So instead of

element.click

use something like

driver.execute_script('var el=arguments[0]; setTimeout(function() { el.click(); }, 100);', element)

Hope it helps, as it is quite straightforward - until this issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

could you provide a UI  screen what kind of dialog you face with?

1) case 1. if it be like jsAlert I would try:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

2) another approach (not considered to be a robust one approach while testing in a parallel way with multiple browser instances) :

//pressing enter on handling dialog box with [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class instance

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.delay(2000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

[Robot class in Java](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t84094.html)  will provide more cases of Robot usage.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: here is an example of the issue I am facing https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/showModalDialog.html I am writing this in c# are you aware of anything similar to the robot class in c#?